# Find the Max, Min, Sum, Average and reverse order of a series of no

Tags: javascript, math

**I need to find the Max, Min, Sum, Average and reverse order of a series of no.**
Create a webpage which will show the output (Max, Min, Sum, Average and Reverse Order) of a series of no. The page should include a form where an input field will be present a series of no. will be given input in the field separated by coma. The program will keep on doing the calculation as I keep on providing a series of no.
Sample:

**Input Series of Number : 12,12,22,9,1,20
Max : 22
Min : 1
Sum : 76
Average : 12.66
Reverse Order : 20,1,9,22,12,12**

Code I try :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title> Series Finder </title>
</head>
<body>

<table width="50%" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="13%">Input Series of Number :</td>
    <td width="29%"><input name="box1" type="text" id="box1"  /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Max :</td>
    <td><div id="result"> </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Min :</td>
    <td><div id="result"> </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sum  :</td>
    <td><div id="result"> </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Average :</td>
    <td><div id="result"> </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Reverse Order :</td>
    <td><div id="result"> </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

<script>

   function calculate() {
        var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
        var res = Math.max([myBox1, myBox1]);

        alert(res);


        result.innerHTML = myResult;


    }
</script>
```

Comment: So you really didn't try anything and looking for some spoon-feeding solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function calculate() {
  var values = document.getElementById('box1').value.split(/,/g);
  var sum = values.reduce(function(a, b) { return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b); });
  document.querySelector('#max').innerHTML = values.max();
  document.querySelector('#min').innerHTML = values.min();
  document.querySelector('#sum').innerHTML = sum;
  document.querySelector('#avg').innerHTML = sum / values.length;
  document.querySelector('#reverse').innerHTML = values.reverse().join(',');
}

Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};

Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(null, this);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title> Series Finder </title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <table width="50%" border="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td width="13%">Input Series of Number:</td>
        <td width="29%"><input name="box1" type="text" id="box1" value="12,12,22,9,1,20" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Max :</td>
        <td><div id="max"> </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Min :</td>
        <td><div id="min"> </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sum  :</td>
        <td><div id="sum"> </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Average :</td>
        <td><div id="avg"> </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Reverse Order :</td>
        <td><div id="reverse"> </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<button onclick="calculate()">calculate</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

ECMAScript 2015 solution:

```
const input = [12, 12, 22, 9, 1, 20];

let max = Math.max(...input);
let min = Math.min(...input);
let sum = input.reduce((r, i) => r + i, 0);
let average = (sum / input.length).toFixed(2);
let reverse = input.slice().reverse();
```